# load bearing beam is failing

Tags: wood

I live in an old house that was barn framed, mortise and tenon joints. One of my weight bearing beams
has split on one side where the beam was mortised and the side of the beam wasn't. the side that was mortised split horizontaly through all the mortises. what is my best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: it is unclear how the beam is split ... you said that the spit is horizontal, but you said nothing about the beam orientation ... please post pictures

Comment: need pictures please